# How to mask values when grouping rows with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, mask

I want to get the mean value for every 7 rows of a column in a file excluding from the mean specific values (i.e.-9999 and 0)

a sample of the file is

```
1 567
2 -9999
3 98
4 77
5 0 
6 89
7 77
8 567
9 -9999
10 87
11 0
12 10 
13 79
14 75
```

I get the mean value for every 7 rows as following:

```
df=pd.read_csv(e,sep='\t',usecols=[1],skiprows=(0),header=None)
data_mean=df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//7).mean() 
data_mean.index=data_week.index+1
data_mean.to_csv(outfile,sep="\t",header=False)
```

In case I would like only to get the mean value of the whole column and use a mask I would do

```
data_mean = df.mask(df.isin([-9999, 0])).mean(1) #to exclude 0 and -9999
```

How I could use the mask in the first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.mask(df.isin([-9999, 0])).groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//7).mean()
```

Comment: I got the error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Should work now, forgot to add `len()`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace -9999 and 0 by NaN:

```
df[df.isin([-9999, 0])] = np.NaN
```

then apply your first code:

```
>>> df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//7).mean()
       1
0  181.6
1  163.6
```